# Cannot resolve method makeText in Android

Tags: java, android, android-toast

I was trying to play with an android toast. But encountered a problem saying `Cannot resolve method makeText`. I searched and found many answers but not a single worked for me.

**Try 1:**

```
if ((fieldvalue.getText().toString()).matches("")) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "You did not enter a username", 
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
}
```

**Try 2:**

```
if ((fieldvalue.getText().toString()).matches("")) {
    public static Toast makeText (this, "You did not enter a username", 
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    return;
}
```

Comment: Toast.makeText(context, "You did not enter a username", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: Nah! not working!!!

Comment: The first snippet would be OK, if `this` is a `Context`. The second snippet is invalid Java.

Comment: @user45154754514656210 Try using `getApplicationContext()` instead of `this` as first argument,

Comment: user45154754514656210 the thing is  if you do it inside a click listener then you should use `YourActivity.this` or if you use inside fragment then you should use`getContext` make sure you are using valid context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `isEmpty()`. Also make sure to define the activityclass with `.this` like `yourclass.this` .

```
if(fieldvalue.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {

Toast.makeText(youractivity.this, "You did not enter a username!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
else{
                    
Toast.makeText(youractivity.this, "Success! :)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
if (fieldvalue.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "You did not enter a username", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
}
```

Comment: Better to explain in your answer how your proposed solution is different from what the OP has tried, how you feel that it should solve the OP's problem

Comment: `matches()` is used for regular expressions. Here it obviously wants to see if it is empty. @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter

Comment: Please [edit] your answer and include important bits in the answer text itself.

Comment: It's clear enough in my idea. Thanks for the suggestion anyway.